# feeding an image to a pretrained keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example) model (straight up copy paste from the website) and saved it with `model.save()`.
I now want to use it to classify images that I generate so I save them and reshape them to 28x28 pixels and then attempt to feed them to the model like so:

```
from matplotlib import image
img = image.imread('img.png')[:,:,:1] #so that the shape ends up being (28,28,1)
print(self.model.predict(img))
```

But when I run this i get a bunch of errors:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28, 1) for input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28, 1, 1).
> ...

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_12 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [None, 28]`
```

I've done some digging around and it seems there's an issue with the shape of the input, according to this line: `WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28, 1) for input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28, 1, 1)`

How do I convert my image into the correct shape?

Comment: `.reshape()` works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to fix it, embarassingly easy but i will leave this here in case anyone else has an issue:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

img = load_img('img.png')
img = img_to_array(img)[:,:,:1]
img = np.expand_dims(img ,axis=0)
```

this changed the shape of my image to `(1, 28, 28, 1)` which is what was needed to feed to the model